# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'CBDB.Subsystem' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I keep getting an error when trying to create the table "Subsystem" in mariadb. I was able to run this in mysql successfully but when trying with mariadb I get errors which i'm guessing are syntax related or somthing i'm missing completly regarding foreign keys.
Here is the tables i'm creating first, trying to create parent tables first...

```
-- Creating Tables 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Storage_Type;
CREATE TABLE Storage_Type (
stor_model VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
stor_class VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
stor_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_stor_model PRIMARY KEY (stor_model)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Service_Level;
CREATE TABLE Service_Level (
serv_level CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
serv_name VARCHAR(30),
serv_maxiops VARCHAR(7),
CONSTRAINT pk_serv_level PRIMARY KEY (serv_level)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Site;
CREATE TABLE Site (
site_num VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
site_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
site_address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
site_suburb VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
site_city VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
site_pcode CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_site_num PRIMARY KEY (site_num)
);

---No sure what i'm doing wrong on this table??
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customer;
CREATE TABLE Customer (
site_num VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
cust_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
site_description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_site_num PRIMARY KEY (site_num),
CONSTRAINT fk_site_num FOREIGN KEY (site_num) REFERENCES Site(site_num)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Pools;
CREATE TABLE Pools (
sub_serial MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
pool_id CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
data_date DATE NOT NULL,
pool_name VARCHAR(30),
pool_type CHAR(4),
pool_totalcapacity INT NOT NULL,
pool_usedcapacity INT NOT NULL,
pool_usedpercent INT,
pool_availablecapacity INT NOT NULL,
pool_subscribedcapacity INT,
pool_subscriptionpercent INT,
serv_level CHAR(2),
CONSTRAINT pk_pool PRIMARY KEY (sub_serial, pool_id, data_date),
CONSTRAINT fk_serv_level FOREIGN KEY (serv_level) REFERENCES Service_Level(serv_level)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Costs;
CREATE TABLE Costs (
cost_date DATE NOT NULL,
serv_level CHAR(2),
cost_gbmonth VARCHAR(10),
cost_gbday VARCHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT pk_cost PRIMARY KEY (cost_date,serv_level),
CONSTRAINT fk_cost FOREIGN KEY (serv_level) REFERENCES Service_Level(serv_level)
);

--------ISSUES creating this table.....
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Subsystem;
CREATE TABLE Subsystem (
sub_serial MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
sub_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
stor_model VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
cust_name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
CONSTRAINT pk_subsys PRIMARY KEY (sub_serial),
CONSTRAINT fk_subsys_stor_model FOREIGN KEY (stor_model) REFERENCES Storage_Type(stor_model),
CONSTRAINT fk_subsys_cust_name FOREIGN KEY (cust_name) REFERENCES Customer(cust_name)
);
```

**the errors:**

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'CBDB.Subsystem' (errno: 150)
```

I ran a - SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and get the following, which i cant seem to pinpoint the issue.

```
> ------------------------ LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
> ------------------------ 171124 16:09:31 Error in foreign key constraint of table `CBDB`.`Subsystem`:  FOREIGN KEY (cust_name)
> REFERENCES Customer(cust_name) ): Cannot find an index in the
> referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first
> columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not
> match for constraint. Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and
> SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns
> in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
```

Any Tips or ideas on where i'm going wrong??

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time and looking at detail of the "show engine innodb status" and referencing this with the mariadb error codes. They indicated that there was an Index missing on the Customer table as the primary key was a referenced value from another table.
I created a Index by:

```
create index idx_cust on Customer(cust_name);
```

after creating the table, however there is syntax in doing within the table creation.
By creating the index I was able to correctly reference the foreign key.
Hopfully this may help others with the slightly vague error messages.